# ROS indigo key server down

Tags: ros, installation, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all;

I am trying to install ROS indigo in a new system, but keyserver is down:

```
alberto@OptiPlex-9010:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.ryx941KSlA --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116
gpg: requesting key B01FA116 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
alberto@OptiPlex-9010:~$
```

Is there any possibility to set up keys manually and continue with installation?
Thank you all in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212254/ros-indigo-key-server-down/) by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill Warner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22938/bill-warner/) on 2015-06-26**:
Have you tried just going ahead and installing (e.g. sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full)? What errors do you get when attempting that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The keyserver seems to be back up now. If it goes down again you can use this to get the key from github over an SSL connection.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5